# Basic Auth example

Tags: ios, basic-authentication

I've been trying to figure out how to make a login page in my app. I have URL, valid username, password. I was told to use basic auth to do it.

So far I implemented this code

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://site-url.com"];

    NSString *loginString =(NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",usernameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];

    NSData *encodedLoginData=[loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString *authHeader=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",  [encodedLoginData base64Encoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:3.0];

    [request setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    // POW, here's the content of the webserver's response.
    NSLog(@"Response -> %@",response);

    int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    NSLog(@"response code:%d",statusCode);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:usernameTextField.text
                                                                    password:passwordTextField.text
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"Connection success.");

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failure.");
```

to make it work but when I use my site URL, it just gives me success message and status code 200 and doesn't call delegate method - willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:

When I change the URL to gmail.com It gives the following output:

> 2013-08-06 12:06:08.674 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] received authentication challenge
>   2013-08-06 12:06:08.674 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Username string:admin
>   2013-08-06 12:06:08.674 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Password string:password
>   2013-08-06 12:06:08.675 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] credential created - > : admin
>   2013-08-06 12:06:08.675 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] responded to authentication challenge
>   2013-08-06 12:06:09.025 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] received authentication challenge
>   2013-08-06 12:06:09.026 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Username string:admin
>   2013-08-06 12:06:09.026 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Password string:password
>   2013-08-06 12:06:09.026 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] credential created - > : admin
>   2013-08-06 12:06:09.026 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] responded to authentication challenge
>   2013-08-06 12:06:10.069 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] received authentication challenge
>   2013-08-06 12:06:10.069 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Username string:admin
>   2013-08-06 12:06:10.069 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Password string:password
>   2013-08-06 12:06:10.069 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] credential created - > : admin
>   2013-08-06 12:06:10.070 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] responded to authentication challenge
>   2013-08-06 12:06:10.457 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Response ->  { URL: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2 } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store";
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Tue, 06 Aug 2013 17:06:09 GMT";
>       Expires = "Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT";
>       Pragma = "no-cache";
>       Server = GSE;
>       "Set-Cookie" = "GAPS=1:LoAnsovSVriBDm6iP1r7zuYy7bTCpQ:3o2OJzkd7X87BrCH;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 06-Aug-2015 17:06:09 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly, GALX=S0GMqJp_fyQ;Path=/;Secure";
>       "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains";
>       "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
>       "X-Auto-Login" = "realm=com.google&args=service%3Dmail%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com%252Fmail%252F";
>       "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
>       "X-Frame-Options" = Deny;
>       "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
>   } }
>   2013-08-06 12:06:10.458 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Status code -> 200
>   2013-08-06 12:06:11.243 CVReaderSGT[26544:a0b] Connection success.

I dont know why I am getting two different outputs when i change URL and why delegate method willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: is not being called when I put my URL.

```
  Here's what the output looks like when using my URL:
   2013-08-06 12:29:06.007 CVReaderSGT[26583:a0b] Response -> <NSHTTPURLResponse:      0x8e20ac0> { URL: http://XYZ.com/ } { status code: 403, headers {
"Content-Length" = 1585;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Tue, 06 Aug 2013 17:29:04 GMT";
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices = "12.0.0.6219";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/6.0";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
   } }
   2013-08-06 12:29:06.007 CVReaderSGT[26583:a0b] Status code -> 403
   2013-08-06 12:29:06.007 CVReaderSGT[26583:a0b] Connection success.
```

I really want to understand the process and make it work.

Can anyone please provide examples or provide right info. thanks.

Comment: Which delegate methods of `NSURLConnection` do you implement?

Comment: @iPinak willReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:

Comment: What do you mean when you put your URL? What's that URL like? Also, what are trying to accomplish. From what I see here you try to authenticate to gmail, right? Which apparently works pretty good.

Comment: I am trying to create login screen where I can successfully login once I provide correct username and password. URL is simpleURL www.xyz.com

Comment: Are you sure that the backend you want to connect to works? Because that might an issue, also what's the error you get from connecting to your URL?

Comment: well it works on the web. I am not entirely sure how basic auth for iOS works.

Comment: It doesn't really matter since it's a header field. Also, if the problem persists and you don't have time I suggest you to use AFNetworking. Pretty good library for networking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34924/discussion-between-akash-and-ipinak)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Authentication delegate methods
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
#pragma mark unused (connection)
    assert(connection == connect);
    assert(protectionSpace != nil);

    BOOL retVal;
    retVal = [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];

    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
{
    // Tries to connect 3 times, after the 3 attempts it cancels.
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] < 3) {
        // Create credentials from the user name and password and save them, for this
        // specific authentication challenge.
        NSURLCredential *credentials = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user password:pass persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
//      [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        // Handle the credentials according the state of the challenge.
        if (challenge == nil) {
            [[challenge sender] continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        else {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
    else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"Wrong username or password");
    }
}

// Save credentials for further use.
- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Take a look at this. This works for me.
Try to change the values here to see which one matches your server requirements.

`retVal = [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];`